# Sharing Folder's which are symbolic links to another folder

Tags: samba

I have to run wine for a program which does not have anything that comes close in linux.  It is not bad, and it runs perfectly under wine.

The program, needs input files and produces a number of output files (which change each day).  I cannot do anything else than store them in the Windows directory structure.  It looks something like this:
`/home/user/.wine/drive_c/users/Public/Application Data/TVxb/......`

Since for the rest of the process I need to excess them in other programs, which run native on Linux, I have created a symbolic link to this folder in the folder which has all the other stuff under the name `/home/EPG/TVxb...`
This works fine on linux.  No problem.

However, I have Windows machine.  Now I have created a share from the linux folder `/home/EPG/` to the Windows machine.  All the stuff is perfectly accessible on the Windows machine.  However the symbolic linked folder to the `/home/user/.wine/drive_c/users/Public/Application Data/TVxb/......` (`/home/EPG/TVxb/`) cannot be opened on my Windows machine.  Denied access.  Although I tried to give both the symbolic link and the actual folder and contents `777` permissions.

I solved this issue by creating a share directly to the `/home/user/.wine/drive_c/users/Public/Application Data/TVxb/......` folder.  This works but it is ugly.

How can I share the symbolic linked folder to another PC?

And if this is not possible, hide the 2 folders in the share which are not accessible.  (making them hidden folders would not do - because in Windows I have show hidden files/folders always on)

Willy

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is caused by this:

https://www.samba.org/samba/news/symlink_attack.html

probably bind mounting /home/user/.wine/drive_c/users/Public/Application Data/TVxb to /home/EPG/TVxb will solve your problem. i.e.:

```
sudo mount --bind "/home/user/.wine/drive_c/users/Public/Application Data/TVxb" "/home/EPG/TVxb"
```